# TLS 1.1 with VS2008 SP1

Tags: c++, ssl, visual-studio-2008

I have a legacy C++ (unmanaged) application build using VS2008 SP1. Currently, it makes calls to the web service hosted on an IIS, and the secure connection is made using SSLv3/TLS1.0. I am planning to make changes to connect using TLS 1.1. Internally, I am using WinINet calls to make connection. Does using VS2008 SP1 have anything to do with TLS1.1? Should I upgrade to a different version of VS (so as to get a new Windows SDK?) just to support TLS 1.1, or will it work with VS2008 SP1? Does anyone have any experience with this type of problem?

Comment: Have you tried using a more recent version of Visual Studio? It might just compile and work, and this question would be moot.

Comment: @zmbq: No, VS is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinInet is no part of VisualStudio and it therefore does not matter if you use VS2008 of VS2015.
I cannot find a clear reference but basically you are using the libraries of IE. (A good hint for this can be found in the IPv6 section, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385325(v=vs.85).aspx - "Starting with IE7 and above, WinINet supports IPv6 ...")
As you might have experienced already, on a system without IE installed some functionality does not work.

Since the WinInet (Windows / IE) supports TLS1.1 (and TLS1.2 for that matter), your program should just work. Even with VS2008.

Forcing the connection to use TLS1.1 or 1.2 is a whole other question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just tunnel the connection throught something like stunnel or a vpn if You have access to client machines